# Laravel Policy - Wrong User transmitted from Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, policy, authorize

I registered a Policy to access User's Profiles (view, edit).
I either allow it if:

- The Profile you are trying to view belongs to you
- You have the Permission "edit any profile".

so this is my `view()`-Function in the Policy:

```
public function view(User $user)
    {
        debug('User in Controller: '.$user->id);
        return (Auth::user()->id === $user->id) || Auth::user()->can('edit any profile');
    }
```

This is method to show the profile view taken from the ProfileController:

```
public function show(User $user) {
        debug('User in Controller: '.$user->id);
        $this->authorize('view', $user);

        return view('profile.index')->with([
            "user" => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

And finally the route:

`Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile');`

Of course, the Policy has been registered in the AuthServiceProvider:

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        User::class => ProfilePolicy::class,
    ];
```

Basically the controller transmits the wrong user to the policy. Here are both messages from the respective `debug()`'s:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't like to answer my own questions but I found out what the problem was. The first Parameter in a policy function is always an instance of the current user.

So you can simply have this in your policy:

```
public function view(User $currentUser, User $user)
    {
        return $currentUser->is($user) || $currentUser->can('edit any profile');
    }
```

Laravel automatically sets `$currentUser` to `Auth::user()`.